# App installation on Android 6 bypasses the customary 'Permissions' screen

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

**Wanna make an app?** - *That's simple!*

**Wanna make it work on different versions?** - *Learn rocket science.*

Have seen the following answers and more, but none helped:

- [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701792/android-app-not-asking-for-permissions-when-installing)
- [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738651/request-permission-on-android-m-only-when-targeting-lower-api?rq=1)
- [Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928868/how-do-we-distinguish-never-asked-from-stop-asking-in-android-ms-runtime-permis?rq=1)

So, here's my `AndroidManifest` chunk:

```
    :    
    :    
    :    
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    :    
    :
```

and the relevant chunk from `build.gradle`:

```
    :    
    :    
android{

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    :    
    :
```

When I first installed the app on Marshmallow (6.0.1), the installer said (something very similar to) - "it requires no special access (or permissions)". The app failed to go beyond the splash screen too, whereas on other Android versions, the sailing is smooth and complete.

The answers listed above explain *why*, (change in the permission model etc.), from which I cannot figure out what really to do.

My requests are:

- Please let me know *how* to make the app install exactly as it installs on lesser versions than 6.0.
- How to keep code changes (if required) to the barest minimum
- How not to complicate the existing, automatic permissions request at install time (with run-time permissions and all that).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Marshmallow. Android M(6.0) introduced [runtime permission model](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). You are suppose to handle requesting for permissions in runtime. You could refer to my [github sample](https://github.com/balaji-katika/android-utils/blob/master/android-commons/src/main/java/com/fourglabs/util/PermissionUtils.java) on how to do it. There are a few other libraries like [easypermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) to enable developer get rid of the hassles.

Comment: Thanks, @Balaji Katika! Needed that welcome :) Are you categorically saying that code change is *mandatory* then? God knows what's waiting with Android N...

Comment: Its mandatory to request permission in M. You need to check the version in Yes @Narayana J your code and need to handle it accordingly :-)